# Finding the first line of the current Vim fold

Tags: vim

I am writing a Vimscript function in which I need to find the line number of the first line of the current fold. So far I have been using this:

```
function! GetFoldStart()
    let l:current_line=line('.')
    normal [z
    let l:current_fold_start=line('.')
    execute 'normal ' . l:current_line . 'g'
endfunction
```

Which works fine, but seems unnecessarily expensive. Is there a cheaper way of achieving it? Basically I need to borrow the functionality of the **[z** command, without actually moving to the line.

I was hoping that the variable v:foldstart would come to my rescue, but it seems only to work correctly for closed folds (for use in foldtext).

Thanks in advance for your Vim wisdom!
Jonathan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use `normal!` (with bang) in scripts, it is safer. Second,

```
let winview=winsaveview()
try
    " Your code here "
finally
    call winrestview(winview)
endtry
```

holds more cases then `let l:current_line=line('.')` ... `execute "normal! ".l:current_line."gg"`.

I don't know a way to obtain information you want without `normal! [z`, but the following code should not modify jumplist:

```
function! GetFoldStart()
    let winview=winsaveview()
    try
        keepjumps normal! [z
        return line(".")
    finally
        keepjumps call winrestview(winview)
    endtry
endfunction
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very good advice (I am long-time Vim user, but a fresh-faced Vim-scripter). I'm still hoping there's an alternative solution though.