# How do I report the first line of each fold in Vim?

Tags: vim

I thought that

```
:folddoc execute v:foldstart."p"
```

would work, but it only repeatedly returns the first line of just *one* of the folds.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776087/finding-the-first-line-of-the-current-vim-fold

Comment: I just tried :folddoclosed execute (GetFoldStart()."p"), and it returns all lines in each fold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line of a closed fold can be detected using the `foldclosed()`
function. For a given line number inside of a closed fold, it returns
the number of the line that fold starts on; otherwise, it returns -1.
Obviously, if a line’s number equals to the value of `foldclosed()`
for that number, then the line is the first one in a fold. In
Vimscript this test can be written as

```
foldclosed('.') == line('.')
```

Therefore, to print the first lines of all closed folds, one can use
the following command:

```
:folddoc if foldclosed('.') == line('.') | # | endif
```

(Use the `:p` command instead of the `:#` one when displaying line
numbers is not necessary.)